# How to move scroll on div move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem.
I have one div. On click I wont to move that div. But I want the div always to be in the center namely when I move the DIV for 10px, for example, and the overflow moves with div (for 10px).
Help please :)

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: What you want is to scroll your body, conserving your div in center of your body view ?

Comment: The stackoverflow community cannot help you, if you do not provide examples of what you have tried, see [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#welcome").hide();
  $("#welcome").fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $("#welcome").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#welcome {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 47vh;
}
#monopol{
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
#welcome h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
#radnja {
   height: 19vh;
   width: 19%;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Monopoly</h1>
  </div>
  <center>
  <div id="monopol">
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
    <div id="radnja">
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to move div from one "radnja" div to second but when move that div 
I want to scroll follow him :)